# Manage the back button with multiple scene

Tags: android, andengine

I followed this tutorial http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/multiple-screen-andengine-game-v2-t4755.html to create a simple application with multiple scene and only one activity.
I'd like to know how can i can return to the previous scene when i use the back button and finish the activity when i'm in the first scene.

I tried so in the MultiScreen Class:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        this.mEngine.getScene().back();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

replacing the `core.getEngine().setScene(scene);` in the SceneManager with `this.mEngine.getScene().setChildScene(scene);`

---

scene work differently from how I understood, I resolve with:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Scene scene = this.mEngine.getScene();
        if(scene.hasChildScene()){
            scene.back();
        }
        else{
            this.finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always good to find the solution yourself :) But post your solution as an answer and remove "RESOLVED:" from the title

Comment: Hey Erick.... you can add delete your answer part from above question and answer it below. and tick it as accepted answer...It would be helpful for future reader

Answer (score 2):

You can override the back key in one of two ways, either by overriding the onBackPressed() method, or the dispatchKeyEvent() method

Overriding onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // your code here
}
```

Overriding dispatchKeyEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        // your code here
    }
    return (yourbooleanhere);
}
```

Comment: but how can i go back from one scene to the previous and exit if i'm in the first scene?

Comment: You can call finish() where it needs to be called. That will exit an activity and take you back to the previous screen. Remember, I'm not programming this for you, the rest is for you to figure out.

Comment: i know how to finish it the problem is that i don't understand how know if the scene is the first becouse don't exist the method hasParentScene()

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't know a whole lot about how android intents work. I would read up on how to start (and finish) a new intent, because that sounds like what you're trying to accomplish. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a dilemma like you in that sense. I explain. I have an activity like works with a ViewFlipper. I need to go to the different "layout" that I wrote on ViewFlipper tag and, when a I was in a particular "layout" that is not the main "layout" of the activity, I need to come back to the main pressing the back button, but, it doesn't work what I want.

To resolve this dilema, I override  `OnBackPressed` function like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (condition) {
        // go to the main 
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

where `condition`, as name says, how do you know that you are in the main "layout"? For example, in my ViewFlipper, the main "layout" are ordered by numbers, that begin on 0, so my main "layout" is 0 and how I know that I am in the 0 "layout", `viewflipper.getDisplayedChild()`. If it returns 0, I stay in the main "layout" or not, otherwise.

So simple but, I know, not so elegant. It's an idea, I think that can help you.