# Displaying Main Menu Scene if back button pressed in Level Menu Scene

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

Need help...
I have a main menu scene from which if gamer clicks on play button he/she will be redirected to Level Menu Scene. The problem is when I click back button of device on Level Menu Scene  whole activity is getting exited.
My expectation is when gamer click device back button system should redirect gamer to Main Menu Scene. I'm using below code in my level menu scene which is not working :-(

```
@Override
public void onBackKeyPressed()
{
 SceneManager.getInstance().createMenuScene(); //to display main menu
}
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730561/resolved-manage-the-back-button-with-multiple-scene) can help you.

Particularly this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Scene scene = this.mEngine.getScene();
    if(scene.hasChildScene()){
        scene.back();
    }
    else{
        this.finish();
    }
}
```